# Activity bot: Going to the corner on the upper right side in a maze

Tags: c

So I am creating a program to drive a robot to the upper right corner in a maze. An example of the maze would be:[image]

And this is my code:

```
#include "simpletools.h"
#include "abdrive.h"
#include "ping.h"


int whichCase = 0;
//int caseArray[] = {0,1,2,3};
int irLeft, irRight;

    void turnRight () {
    drive_goto(26, -25);
    drive_goto(125,125);
    whichCase = (whichCase + 1) % 4;
    }

    void turnLeft () {

    whichCase = (whichCase - 1) % 4;
    drive_goto(-25,26);
    drive_goto(125,125);
    }


    void forward () {
     drive_goto(125,125);
    }

    void backward(){
    drive_goto(26, -25);
    drive_goto(26, -25);
    whichCase = (whichCase + 2) % 4;
    }


    void priority(int whichCase) {

    switch (whichCase) {

    case (0):

    /* (1) go right */ if (irRight == 1) {   turnRight();  }
    /* (2) go forward */ else if (ping_cm(8) > 30) {  forward(); }
    /* (3) go left */ else if (irLeft == 1) { turnLeft(); }
    /* (4) go backward */ else if (irRight == 0 && irLeft == 0 && ping_cm(8) < 30){ backward();}
    break;


    case (1):
    /* (1) go forward */  if (ping_cm(8) > 30) {  forward(); }
    /* (2) go left */  else if (irLeft == 1) { turnLeft(); }
    /* (3) go backward */else if (irRight == 0 && irLeft == 0 && ping_cm(8) < 30){ backward();}
    /* (4) go right */ else if (irRight == 1) {  turnRight();  }
    break;


    case (2):
    /* (1) go left */   if (irLeft == 1) { turnLeft(); }
    /* (2) go backward */ else if (irRight == 0 && irLeft == 0 && ping_cm(8) < 30){ backward();}
    /* (3) go right */ else if (irRight == 1) {  turnRight();  }
    /* (4) go forward */  else if (ping_cm(8) > 30) { forward(); }
    break;

    case (3):
    /* (1) go backward */ if (irRight == 0 && irLeft == 0 && ping_cm(8) < 30){ backward();}
    /* (2) go right */ else if (irRight == 1) {  turnRight();  }
    /* (3) go forward */  else if (ping_cm(8) > 30) {  forward(); }
    /* (4) go left */   else if (irLeft == 1) { turnLeft(); }
    break;


            }

    }

    void main () {
    drive_goto(145,145);
    low(26);                                      // D/A0 & D/A1 to 0 V
    low(27);
    drive_setRampStep(12);
    freqout(11, 1, 38000);                      // Check left & right objects
    irLeft = input(10);
    freqout(1, 1, 38000);
    irRight = input(2);

    while(1) {
    priority(whichCase);
    }

  }
```

So in this code I basically made 4 cases representing the different positions of the robot: facing up, facing right, facing down and left. And depending on the position the robot will use its sensors differently. And the idea of the code is this:

1. if it can go right, go right
2. else if it can go forward go forward
3. else if it can go left go left
4. else if it can go back go back

I think the logic is very simple annd it should work. but it does not.

Please help :(

Comment: What exactly the issue you are seeing? "but it does not" is not a useful problem description.

Comment: the logic of my code. I thought the logic was simple but it did not work. It turned left when it should have turned right. i really cannot find any error in my code.

Comment: You should check out the "snipping tool" for taking screenshots. Unless you're dealing with a kernel panic / BSOD, a photo of your monitor is very unprofessional, especially in the tech world.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Sorry. I just googled kernel panic and BSOD. I didn't know what they mean and I assumed they were something insulting. It is my fault. I am really sorry.

Comment: @TommyLassa No problem. We may be terse around here but we're generally not assholes :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As B. Wolf suggested, you need to update the irLeft and irRight in the while loop. Furthermore, yours seems like a wall follower, and it will just follow the wall (endlessly). You need to add an end condition to your code, as in you need to keep track in which square of the maze you are at the time being. As the mazes are 4x4, you'll know exactly when to stop in this manner

I'll remind you that you need to visit all 3 other corners during Phase 1, so just getting to the opposite corner won't work. 
Yes, I am one of your coursemates, and you're better off asking fellow coursemates who finished the assignment, apart from people from stack overflow who do not know the full extent of the coursework :)

Comment: oh god hahahahaha. yeah i have done the first part :) This is actually funny hahal. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Update irLeft and irRight within your while(1) loop. Find out how to use a debugger, or print debugging information to watch variables.